# Why two different results are given when using str.format()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to extract the maximum closing and its corresponding date from yahoo finance and annotate the point on the graph. The code is shown below.

```
ymax = tencents[['Close']].max() 
ymax
#result: Close    474.600006
dtype: float64

texty= "y={:.3f}".format(ymax)
texty
#result: unsupported format string passed to Series.__format__
#expected: 474.60

xmax= tencents['Close'].idxmax()
#result: "x=.strftime('2018-01-23)"
textx= "x={:.strftime('%Y-%m-%d)}".format(xpos)
textx
result: "x=.strftime('2018-01-23)"
```

When I combine the two:

```
text = "x={:.strftime('%Y-%m-%d)},y={:} ",format(xpos,ymax)
text

#result: format() argument 2 must be str, not Series

#expected: (2018-01-23, 474.60)
```

Comment: What is `xpos`? Please provide a  **complete, minimal, and verifiable** example.

Comment: That being said. `"x={:.strftime('%Y-%m-%d)},y={:} ",format(xpos,ymax)` should be `"x={:.strftime('%Y-%m-%d)},y={:} ".format(xpos,ymax)` and I think you want to add a `'` after `%Y-%m-%d`

Comment: typo, xpos should be xmax

Comment: Did the answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Watch your commas (`,`). In python a comma is often read as a tuple.

So though your code is valid this does not do what you think it does:
`text = "x={:.strftime('%Y-%m-%d)'},y={:} ",format(xmax, ymax)`

What you meant to do is:
`text = "x={:.strftime('%Y-%m-%d)'},y={:} ".format(xmax, ymax)`

```
from datetime import datetime

ymax = 474.600006


texty= "y={:.3f}".format(ymax)
print(texty)

xmax= datetime.today()

textx= "x={:.strftime('%Y-%m-%d)}".format(xmax)
print(textx)

# Here you had `,`format(xpos, ymax)
text = "x={:.strftime('%Y-%m-%d)'},y={:} ".format(xmax, ymax)

print(text)
# result: "x=.strftime('2018-01-23)"
```